# highchart created using value from mysql, how to export it using phantomjs

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, phantomjs

Phantomjs installed on windows system running php 5.3.1 , mysql and apache. I am building an application that generate highchart graph by fetching data from mysql. I want to export highcharts using phantomjs to my server, this work perfactly by executing phantomjs command in php (), this work fine as it export the chart to my server. Now problem is that i can only pass static value to graph.js which shows a static graph, i want to pass values of servies from mysql. how can i achieve this ....

any help plz...........

Comment: I advice to familair with the article aout preprocessing data http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
data: [['Male', 84],
['Female', 77]
]
```

i want this 84 and 77 must be fetch from mysql using php and fill this variable.

Comment: Hello on StackOverflow. If this is not an answer, then remove that and update your question. Otherwise no one will get notification about your post.